# Is Design Manager really available in Foundation 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, 2013, design-manager

During my search, I saw that Design Manager is available, but it appears that we cannot activate the publishing feature over a site or a site collection (which is mandatory to use the manager)

[Is design manager available in foundation](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/c65dbfb2-593a-41e5-a3ad-57ecdce5abb5/is-desgn-manager-available-in-foundation)

As you can see it seems to be unavailable but can you confirm this information?

Comment: I try to activate it with this tutorial : http://www.idubbs.com/blog/2012/sharepoint-2013-enabling-design-manager/ but the options are missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the official feature matrix [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819267.aspx), you can see under "SharePoint feature availability across on-premises solutions that Design Manager is **not** supported in SharePoint Foundation

Comment: Many thanks, I didnt' watch the good matrice, that's why x)